# Delete file owned by root in dired mode

Tags: dired

I am trying to delete a file that is owned by root from Emacs `dired` opened as a regular user.

I get the following error:

`(file-error Removing old name Permission denied /opt/file)`

How can I execute this command with root privileges?

Comment: There is a package called dired-toggle-sudo

Answer (score 5):

Use Tramp. Instead of running `dired` in `/opt`, run it in `/sudo::/opt`. This gives you root permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Put the cursor on the line with the file and type:
! sudo rm